# Different message payload for two debug nodes from single output

Tags: smart-lights, lighting, node-red

In NodeRed, I am seeing a different message payload sent to two debug nodes that are connected to the same output.

[image: Two debug nodes on a single output]

Here is the debug output. Take note of the identical message id, and the different 'bri' value.

[image]

When I export the nodes, it all looks correct:

```
[
{
    "id": "5e606454b87b03b5",
    "type": "AnamicoLightChanged",
    "z": "34538bcf724fc14b",
    "name": "${LIGHT_NAME}",
    "lights": "14cd068baff7afb8",
    "mode": "LIFX",
    "x": 1240,
    "y": 300,
    "wires": [
        [
            "6c7a0670390f6da6",
            "5b8374e42193a04d"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "6c7a0670390f6da6",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "34538bcf724fc14b",
    "name": "LS OUT 1",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "true",
    "targetType": "full",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1500,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "5b8374e42193a04d",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "34538bcf724fc14b",
    "name": "LS OUT 2",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "true",
    "targetType": "full",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1500,
    "y": 340,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "14cd068baff7afb8",
    "type": "AnamicoLights",
    "name": "Anamico Lights"
}
]
```

Can anyone give me an explanation as to what could cause this? Is it something the source node (https://github.com/Anamico/node-red-contrib-light) is doing wrong somehow? Or is it something I am not understanding about the way NodeRed works?

Comment: What is feeding this system. Looking at the node's docs it implies that node is the output from other nodes that take light states as input?

Comment: The 'AnamicoLights' node is a central store of light state, and the 'AnamicoLightChanged' node is meant to send out a message whenever a particular light changes. The central store state changes based on inputs from light monitoring nodes (e.g. you used the LIFX app to change the light), or from an Anamico 'updates' node (e.g. you have some switch you want to use to control the light). I first ran into this when I was writing a HomeKit device to the updates node, but I've also made it happen by just injecting a manual input message.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in NodeJS is pass by reference, so it appears that something in the node is sharing a reference to a single `msg` object and updating it in the gap between the 2 debug nodes processing the message.

They should be the "same" `msg` object because the `msg._msgid` is the same. which also leads to the assumption that something is updating the `msg.payload` independently.

This feels to me that there is something strange in the Anamico node, but it will take time to dissect it to work out what.

Comment: Thanks, this was my feeling too, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious about NodeRed as I only recently discovered it. I had a quick look at the node's source and saw that it was using node.send. The docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#sending-messages-asynchronously) say that each message sent is cloned to avoid problems like this... but is that only for the "function" node, and not custom nodes?

Comment: Not every message is cloned (as this can have a large performance overhead), there are some rules to do with the down stream flow, which wouldn't come into play if it was something upstream changing the message. (The docs you are looking at are specifically for function nodes which is not the same as other nodes, [here](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js#sending-messages) is the doc for a node)

Comment: Thanks, I think that explains it then... the first message I see is the "old" state of the light, and the second one is the "new" state. I think it must be getting something wrong somehow, and editing the payload after the first message has been sent.